# Check if a word is included in the array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I tried this on IRB, but couldn't find the solution:

```
irb(main):001:0> STATUS = %w(draft public)
=> ["draft", "public"]
irb(main):003:0> s = "draft"
=> "draft"
irb(main):004:0> s.include?(STATUS)
TypeError: can't convert Array into String
    from (irb):4:in `include?'
    from (irb):4
    from /Users/SO/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p374/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

What's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish ? Check if any word in `STATUS` is in `s`? If so, your expression is reversed.

Comment: Why not `STATUS.include?(s)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

depa is correct, it is the other way around; however, Rails also provides an [`in?`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#in) method through ActiveSupport that will allow you to use `s.in?(STATUS)`, if that makes more sense to you.

Answer (score 4):

It's the other way around.

```
STATUS.include?(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You got the receiver and the argument the other way around. Check your title: you wrote "a word is included in the array" in passive. If it were in active, it would be "the array includes a word" or `the_array.include?(a_word)`, not `a_word.include?(the_array)`.